# Write SOAP Message to Standard output using JDK Api only

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I'd need to dump a SOAP Message (Java EE Container) on the output stream. I'm currently using an example from a [tutorial](http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jboss-web-services/web-services-handler-chains-tutorial) which requires a handler:

```
 public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
    Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) 
    smc.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    if (!outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {

       SOAPMessage message = smc.getMessage();

       ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       message.writeTo(stream);

    }
}
```

The thing is that this example uses **org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream** so I need to package an external library to my code. Is it possible to write the SOAPMessage on the standard output using plain JDK classes ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you could use the javaIO package to get the same Functionality

**java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream**